# how to send photo by telegram bot using multipart/form-data

Tags: python, telegram, multipartform-data, python-telegram-bot

I have a telegram bot (developed in python) and i wanna to **send/upload photo** by it from images that are in my computer.

so i should do it via multi part form data.

but i don't know ho to do it. also i didn't find useful source for this on Internet and on telegram documentation .

i tried to do that by below codes. but it was wrong

```py
data = {'chat_id', chat_id}
files = {'photo': open("./saved/{}.jpg".format(user_id), 'rb')}
status = requests.post("https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/sendPhoto", data=data, files=files)
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Try this line of code**

```
status = requests.post("https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/sendPhoto?chat_id=" + data['chat_id'], files=files)
```

Answer (score 3):

Both answers by *Delimitry* and *Pyae Hlian Moe* are correct in the sense that they work, but neither address the actual problem with the code you supplied.

The problem is that `data` is defined as:

```
data = {'chat_id', chat_id}
```

which is a **set** (not a dictionary) with two values: a string *'chat_id'* and the content of `chat_id`, instead of

```
data = {'chat_id' : chat_id}
```

which is a **dictionary** with a key: the string *'chat_id'* and a corresponding value stored in `chat_id`.

`chat_id` can be defined as part of the url, but similarly your original code should work as well - defining data and files as parameters for `requests.post()` - as long as both `data` and `files` variables are dictionaries.

Comment: How can i define `files` as a part of the url and not as a parameter?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `chat_id` parameter in URL:

```
files = {'photo': open('./saved/{}.jpg'.format(user_id), 'rb')}
status = requests.post('https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/sendPhoto?chat_id={}'.format(chat_id), files=files)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem already solved by [aiogram](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram) python framework.

This is full example. Just edit TOKEN and PHOTO_PATH, run the code and send /photo command to the bot :)

```py
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor
from aiogram.types import InputFile, Message

TOKEN = "YourBotToken"
PHOTO_PATH = "img/photo.png"

bot = Bot(TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=["photo"])
async def your_command_handler(message: Message):
    photo = InputFile(PHOTO_PATH)
    await message.answer_photo(photo)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```